# Need explanation to understand the following java import statement

Tags: java

The following is an SCJP question. I couldn't understand how the specified answer is correct. Can anyone help?

[image]

The following are the options:

1. A. package xcom;
2. B. import xcom.A;
3. C. import xcom.B;
4. D. package xcom; import xcom.*;

The answer is given as C. It says TestXcom.java need not know anything about A.class. I couldn't understand this explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C" is definitely the right answer.

- Any answer that requires `package xcom` is incorrect, because `TestXcom` is outside the `xcom` package
- Answer "B" is incorrect, because it does not let us use `class B`, only `class A`.

This leaves us with answer "C".

Note that this test is too easy to guess. A choice for "B" saying

> ```
> B. import xcom.A; import xcom.B;
> ```

would be a lot harder to answer, because the student would need to examine `main()` more closely to see that only the `xcom.B` class is used, not `xcom.A`. The fact that `B` extends `A` does not make it a requirement to import `A` in the code that uses `B`.

Using `import xcom.*` would be another valid possibility.

Comment: But adding package xcom; to the source file will compile and when we move the generated class file to xcom directory it will run too.

Comment: @Phoenix The question does not let you change the directory structure or more files around. It lets you change the content of a single file, namely, `TestXcom.java`.

Answer (score 1):

> It says `TestXcom.java` need not know anything about A.class. I couldn't
>   understand this explanation.

Class `TestXcom` doesn't directly use class A, So, there is no need to import it into `TestXcom`.

And Class B and A are in same package, So, Class B don't need to import class A.

Answer (score -1):

It is because class TestXCom does not reference A, but just B. The reference to A might not be there in another implementation of B, so the import of A is not required.